# How do i erase everything but EEPROM with avrdude?

Tags: c, avr, jtag, eeprom, avrdude

I have 2 main files. One writes to EEPROM, other reads from EEPROM. I want to do the following:

- Flash main.hex (the one which writes onto EEPROM)
- Erase everything but the contents of EEPROM
- Flash main.hex (the one which reads from EEPROM)

I am using **AT90CAN128** with **JTAG ICE mkII**, on Windows 7.
I execute avrdude by:

```
avrdude -c jtag2 -p c128 -P usb -U flash:w:main.hex
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear EESAVE fuse. With this feature enabled, a chip erase command will not erase the EEPROM.

Comment: You read the `avrdude` manual section which explains how to set fuses.